# white status bar showing when exit from full screen from MPMoviewPlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

-> My entire app has status bar hidden only. My app support all orientations.

-> When i play video from MPMoviePlayerController in potrait mode and enters into full screen and then i press done button so far works fine.

->But while playing the video(potrait mode) and enters full screen and then i turned device into Landscape, now i pressed done button , a white status bar is showing. How to solve that one. Please help me

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653236/hide-statusbar-from-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: @Hanuman i have seen that link. But i should not use MPMoviePlayerViewController and i should not add MPMoviePlayerController view on the window.

Comment: This issue only appear in Simulator. iPhone / iPad does not have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add "Status bar is initially hidden - YES" on you apps main plist file? and also try this - `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:true];` i hope it will help..